# Xamarin Forms Icons not rendered correctly in TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am trying to get a TabbedPage to work correctly, i.e. I want the menu to be shown at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="App.View.TabbedPageNavigation"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:tabView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.SfTabView.XForms"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.View">
    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <local:HikeList Title="My Hikes">
            <local:HikeList.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="iconmydiaries.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </local:HikeList.Icon>
        </local:HikeList>

        <local:HikeList Title="Friends">
            <local:HikeList.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="iconfriendsdiaries.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </local:HikeList.Icon>
        </local:HikeList>

        <local:SettingsPage Title="Settings" Icon="iconsettings.png">
            <local:SettingsPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="iconsettings.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </local:SettingsPage.Icon>
        </local:SettingsPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

The problem is, that the icons look like in the following image:
[TabbedMenu Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEieK.png)

The interesting thing is that if I remove the line with the "ToolbarPlacement", the images are being rendered just fine (except they of course appear at the top of the page). Note also that the size of the menu items is different, so it seems as if the images are actually being loaded however they are rendered incorrectly. Does anyone know what happens there and how I can fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems as if the Tabbed menu behaves completely different on the bottom. If its on the top, it rendes the actual image. If its on the bottom, it uses the icon as a template where it only colors every pixel that is not transparent. Does anybody know, how I can achieve the same behaviour from the top at the bottom?

Comment: Did you check your Xamarin.Android libraries versions ? What are they ?